# Как заполнить мультиязычный массив с ключами локлей VUE3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Доброе время суток, очень прошу вашей помощи, необходимо заполнить массив с данными, где ключ является локалью. Делаю собственно все как описано ниже, но получаю логичную ошибку ReferenceError: locale is not defined...
Это мой первый проект на VUE да еще и с мультиязычными данными которые я должен отправить на сервер, очень прошу вашей помощи или идей как это можно реализовать иначе.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const locales = ['ru', 'en']

const article = ref({
    id: '',
  translations: {
    [locale]: {
      name: '',
      content: '',
      meta_h1: '',
      meta_description: '',
      slug: '',
    },
  },
    image: null,
})
</script>

<template>
    <div v-for="(locale, index) in locales" :key="index">
        <v-input
            v-model="article.translations[locale].name"
            name="name"
            label="Name"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно `locale` он не знает. Вы же его не определили, и в изначальный объект положили. На его месте судя по всему и должны быть `ru` или `en`.

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    
    const locales = ['ru', 'en'];
    const article = ref({
      id: '',
      translations: {
        "ru": {
          name: 'Russian',
          content: '',
          meta_h1: '',
          meta_description: '',
          slug: '',
        },
        "en": {
          name: 'English',
          content: '',
          meta_h1: '',
          meta_description: '',
          slug: '',
        },
      },
      image: null,
    })
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <div v-for="(locale, index) in locales" :key="index">
        <input
          v-model="article.translations[locale].name"
          name="name"
          label="Name"
        />
      </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: т.есть в computed или в OnMounted нужно взять локали и изменить изменить обьект article ? ведь я для примера написал const locales (они берутся по апи)

Comment: да, через OnMounted можно загрузить

Comment: можно ли в изначальном обьекте при определнии его, не указывать локали? зачем двойная работа и в v-for локаль и в изначальном обьекте ?(

Comment: не очень ясно, у вас article без локалей приходит?

Comment: это шаблон создание записи дальше локализированные данные будут приходить в массиве, где ключ это локаль (ru en uk и тд)

Comment: Делайте изначально пустым ref(null) к примеру. И по onMounted  записывайте туда данные